# How to make webpack inject styles in the "style" attribute of tags?

Tags: css, webpack

I was wondering if there was a webpack package that would inject the styles in the `style` attributes of corresponding tags.

Raw HTML:

```
<p class="par">
  <span class="blue"></span>
</p>
```

Raw CSS:

```
.par { margin-top: 10px; }
.par .blue { color: blue; }
```

Bundled:

```
<p style="margin-top: 10px;"><span style="color: blue;"></span></p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: is this what you looking for? https://github.com/broadly/css-inliner

Comment: it could be, but it seems that it hasn't been updated in a while, the last commits were 4 years ago and my console is very red after trying to use it :) thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack loader works at a file level and hence, you cannot achieve this with any kind of loader. The next best option is plugin, but unfortunately, no such Webpack plugin exists! (This is a pretty opinionated and a complex problem. You may be using plethora of CSS selectors like classNames, ids, attribute or sibling based selectors, pseudo classes, etc. may of which cannot be expressed with just inline `style` attribute).

The closest thing you can get is embedding styles in the HTML document using `<style />` tag with standard `style-loader` and `css-loader`.

And, if your raw CSS is external to your code, you can use the [CSS inline plugin](https://github.com/Runjuu/html-inline-css-webpack-plugin) which is well maintained.

Finally, if you need to do this yourself, either you need to write your own plugin or you can post-process your generated HTML file. I will highly recommend using something like [htmlparser2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) to rewrite your HTML with inline styles.

> *On a side note, it looks like you are trying to use Webpack for statically generated HTML pages (like a static site-builder) and not for bundling your SPA. In those cases, there are more better alternatives.*

Comment: thanks for the answer! to be honest I'm surprised there is no such plugin for webpack. it's as if nobody has ever had the task of building outlook-compliant HTML files (as far as I'm aware, Outlook ignores all styles but the ones in the `style` attributes)

Comment: @akrick Writing HTML for outlook or emails in general is a completely different universe. I strongly suggest not using bundler at all. Just head over to MJML or something like https://react.email/. They are the bundle/component system in themselves.